storage permission is granted but i still get "permission denied"
I request manageExternalStorage Permission, but when i try to list directory content i always get permission denied. Do i need anything else?
Future<void> getFiles() async {
    const permission = Permission.manageExternalStorage;
    bool granted = await permission.isGranted;
    if(!granted) {
      if(!await permission.request().isGranted) return;
    }
    final Directory root = findRoot(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
    await root.list(recursive: true);
    // ...
}

Directory findRoot(FileSystemEntity entity) {
  final Directory parent = entity.parent;
  if (parent.path == entity.path) return parent;
  return findRoot(parent);
}

The permission request worked and i gave permission. Since then it says granted, but i still get the exception.
Here is my Android.manifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="formation_player"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>

This is the exception that is thrown:
PathAccessException: Directory listing failed, path = '/' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Make sure you are handling the “MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” permission correctly.
you should use logs or print  to see if you got the permission or not
{ final permission = Permission.manageExternalStorage;
if (!await permission.isGranted) {
if (await permission.request().isGranted) { // Permission granted, continue }
else { // Permission denied,
print("Permission not getting");
//handle accordingly
return ; } }


you can also use try and catch to see what kind of problem you are getting


ther permission is being granted... but the Exception is still thrown
